# Set Wallpaper of iPhone and Android - Appcelerator

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, titanium, appcelerator

How can I set the wallpaper of iPhone and Android from with in App. Is there any API defined by Appcelerator I searched on google but no solution found.

Answer (score 1):

For iPhone there is no any method or API for it through Titanium Appcelerator.

But for Android there is a code which help you for set direct wallpaper.

```
var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
    action: Ti.Android.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA,
    type: "image/*"
});
intent.addCategory(Ti.Android.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
intent.setData('/IMAGE PATH/', "image/jpeg");
intent.putExtra("mimeType", "image/jpeg");
var intentChooser = Ti.Android.createIntentChooser(intent, "Set as:");
Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity(intentChooser);
```

Hope this help you out.

Comment: Thanks for the response i'll check this out